# How can I set the background color below (and to the right) of table cells if there are few rows (or colums)?

Tags: swing

i have jtable with 5 rows but the size of jtable is more than the jtable containing 10 rows.
when i used table.setBackground(), only 5 rows are colored and rest part is uncolored.

I want to set color in the whole table.

How can i fixed this problem??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Or, make the table fill the whole view port by using the `JTable#setFillsViewportHeight( true )` method. This will fix your background color problem, and has some other advantages as described in the [Swing tutorial about `JTable`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show)

Comment: +1. I didn't know this property, and this answer is better than mine.

Comment: I discovered this property only 2 days ago. Never thought I would be able to use this knowledge on such short notice

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing below the table is probably the background of the viewport of the JScrollPane which contains the JTable.

Set this viewport's background as well:

```
scrollPane.getViewPort().setBackground(Color.white);
```

Comment: while technically correct (if you use the table's background instead hard-coding an arbitrary color), it has an usability issue: it appears like all the area _is_ the table but in fact that's not the case. Consequently users expect that f.i. showing popup menus by mouse clicks are working everywhere.

Comment: Good point. I just saw Robin's answer, and it's better than mine.